# MSAA Automation get_accChildCount for Infragistics UltraWinTree Works Only When Running Under the CLR

Tags: c++, .net, c++-cli, accessibility, ui-automation

I recently asked the following question [MSAA UI Automation get_accChildCount Incorrectly Returning 0 for Infragistics UltraTree in Winforms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32504150/msaa-ui-automation-get-accchildcount-incorrectly-returning-0-for-infragistics-ul) and found an unsatisfying answer that is the reason for asking this question.

Here is the situation:

Process 1: C#/WinForms application showing a UI Window with an Infragistics UltraWinTree that has a handle with value "hwnd".

Process 2: C++ code that is retrieving the number of accessible children of the UltraWinTree that has a handle with value "hwnd" using the following C++ code to invoke MSAA

```
IAccessible* accessibleObj;
AccessibleObjectFromWindow(hwnd, OBJID_CLIENT, IID_IAccessible, (void**)&accessibleObj);
long childCount;
accessibleObj->get_accChildCount(&childCount);
```

If Process 2 is built using the Microsoft C++ compiler with the /clr compiler flag specified (which compiles the code to .NET MSIL instead of assembly) childCount is the correct number. If it is built without the /clr compiler flag specified childCount is an incorrect number and inserting a call to `GetLastError` after the call to `AccessibleObjectFromWindow` returns 2 (which appears to be "File Not Found").

<s>Why does this C++ code work only when the /clr flag to the compiler is specified?</s>

**EDIT**

To be really specific about the answer I am looking for, my primary goal is to get this code to run as C++. So if there is some way to get this C++ code to work without using the /clr option on the Microsoft C++ compiler that will be an accepted answer.

I would really like to know why it magically works when flipping on the /clr flag as well, but that isn't necessary for an answer to be accepted. If you can do both you will have my deepest gratitude :)

Comment: Well, C++/CLI is a very different beast than C++.

Comment: C++/CLI is just C++ plus some language extensions. The Microsoft C++ compiler can compile it as regular C++ if no language extensions are used or else compile it to MSIL for .NET using the /clr compiler switch. The business logic code I am using doesn't utilize any of the extensions so it is just vanilla C++ code.

Comment: I updated the question and hope that it is more clear now. If there are any other issues please let me know.

Comment: Building with `nullptr` in C++/CLI works properly. I even went to far as to decompile the MSIL from a small test project that used `nullptr` and it just maps to `null` in .NET. So getting back to your original complaint that this question shouldn't relate to C++, do you have a specific technical argument as to why the four lines of code that I have posted in my edited question are not related to C++? They build and run just fine (outside of the obvious issue of returning an unexpected value for `childCount`) using the Microsoft C++ compiler.

Comment: Just to avoid mincing words on my last comment, "maps to `null` in .NET" should be understandable what was meant but isn't 100% technically correct. To do that it should read "maps to the same .NET MSIL as `null` from C# for the example used". I had ILSpy set to decompile the .NET assembly to C#.

Comment: You asked me to have fun porting `nullptr` from C++ to C++/CLI. So to have "fun" I ported it for an example, but it worked perfectly fine so there was no "fun". The code in my question is plain old C++ that should work but doesn't. For whatever reason if the identical code is compiled using the Microsoft C++ compiler and the /clr compiler switch it works just fine. Since you seem to care about the differences between C++ and C++/CLI can you explain the answer to my question and in a technical way explain why compiling the same code with /clr fixes the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use MTA (call CoInitializeEx(NULL, COINIT_MULTITHREADED)).